# Displaying a picture with tkinter by calling its path from a csv file

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to display a picture by taking its path from a csv file but every time I try, I get the error `error : _tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "Image test.png": no such file or directory`

After retrieving the file, creating the Window "pageFilm" and creating the variable `moviePoster = PhotoImage ( file = allinfo[10] )` I added the code :

```
Image=Label ( pageFilm , bg = "orange" , image = moviePoster , width = 28 , height = 20 )
Image.configure ( highlightbackground = "orange" )
Image.place ( x = 40 , y = 50 )
```

I have tried to specify that allinfo[10] should be a string by doing `str(allinfo[10])` and I did verify that the name of the picture was good. I also tried to specify the whole path from C: to the picture and tried to replace the spaces by `_` but nothing worked.

After asking the question to a french python community and searching on stackoverflow I didn't find anything. That's why I ask here.

EDIT :
After trying with only the picture's path in the file it did work but when I put informations before it does not work

And to read the file I use this :

```
def RecupFichierInfo () :


    fileInfo = open ( 'Inventaire projet series.csv' , 'r' )
    infoName = fileInfo.readline ()
    infoAll = []
    while 1 :
        info = fileInfo.readline()
        if info == "" :
            break
        infoAll = infoAll + [info.split(',')]
    fileInfo.close()
    nbr = len (infoAll)
    print (infoAll)
    print (nbr)
    return infoAll , nbr
```

When I call the fonction the infoAll list is named allinfo.

Comment: Did you meant ```print(os.getcwd())``` ? If so, yes. When I say "_I also tried to specify the whole path from C: to the picture and tried to replace the spaces by ```_```_"   I copy/paste the path by doing this command.

Comment: Yes. At first, the picture was in a different folder so I specified the path to follow but after that I tried with the picture in the same folder calling only the name of the picture (which did not work) and then calling the whole path(didn't work either). The whole path was the exact same path that the command  ```print(os.getcwd())``` gave me.

Comment: In the same programme, I need to display an other picture which i call by writing the path (I don't use the .csv file here) and it does work. Even if the picture is in a sub-folder.

Comment: Yes there is but the path isn't the last information of the line plus the error does not show any _/n_ in the name of the picture so I dont think it is the problem.

Comment: The csv encoding is **Windows-1252/WinLatin 1** (I'm french so I need accents...) and I use python 3.8.2
I tried your command it does gives the error ```TypeError: string argument without an encoding```

Comment: My bad, should be `print(bytes(allinfo[10].encode(<your encoding>)))`. Try `with open('some.csv', newline='', encoding=<your encoding>) as f:`

Comment: Actually your image filename is "test.png" or "Image test.png"?

Comment: @stovfl This command gives me ```b'test_picture.png'``` which is the name of the picture and in the .csv file i have written **test_picture.png**
Adding the encoding isn't a bad idea but it still doesn't work (testing either with the whole path and without).                                                                              
@acw1668 At this time the name of the picture is test_picture.png but I have verified everywhere and the error gives me the good path and the good name of the picture.

Comment: This is contradict: ***TclError: couldn't open "Image test.png":***  and ***`b'test_picture.png'***. Please stay with **One** filename and show the unedited error message.

Comment: At this day, the picture is named **test_picture.png**, when I do the command ```print(bytes(allinfo[10].encode('CP1252')))``` gives me ```b'test_picture.png``` and the error is ```_tkinter.TclError: image "C:\Users\Youllou\Downloads\Cours\ISN\PopCornTime\Application\test_picture.png" doesn't exist``` if I use the whole path and ```_tkinter.TclError: image "test_picture.png" doesn't exist``` if I don't use the whole path.
Sorry, I have tested many thing so I have done many changes on the picture name but every time I have verified everywhere the name of the picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I dont really know how but I've manage to make it work. I think specifying the encoding helped a lot. Anyway thank you all for the help.

(and sorry for the inconvenience)